# Why is my code not appending correctly into an existing file?

Tags: python-3.x

When I run my code, there are no syntax errors, but it is not appending into the file. Basically, the user inputs their class and name (although this appears at the start of the program) and the program formulates a folder name and a file name - the file name being the user's name. The program then checks in the appropriate folder whether there is an existing file under the same name. If there isn't, the program creates a file in the correct folder and writes the user's score. The next time the same user runs the program, the file should be found. Python does output "File found", but the user's second score is not appended into the file. Any help on how to fix this?

All help is appreciated, thanks

```
Class_number = (input("Please enter your class: "))
score = (input("Please enter your score: "))

Folder = ("Class" + (Class_number))
File_name = (Name) + ".txt"
path = os.path.join("/Computing/a453/Task 3/",(Folder),(File_name))
if os.path.exists(path):
    print("File found")
    file = open((File_name), "a")
    file.write((score) + "\n")
    file.close()
else:
    print("File not found. Creating file")
    CompleteFile = os.path.join(Folder, File_name)         
    file = open(CompleteFile, "w")
    file.write((score) + "\n")
    file.close()
```

Comment: You don't need all those parentheses around variables such as `(score)`, `(File_name)` etc. I think they're only needed for  functions, tuples and generators

Comment: I only use them because I think it makes it easier to read and identify where I have used variables. I understand that they are probably not necessary :P

Comment: Ok, it could cause confusion if you accidentally ended up casting something to a tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

You are checking if the file is present in a subfolder. If it is not present you create a new file in the desired folder and add the first score. If the file is present you are opening **a different file!** In the second case, the call to open just uses the filename without the folder (`open(File_name, "a")`) and not the whole path (`open(CompleteFile, "w")`).

### Further Reading

Is there a special reason why you have to decide whether or not the file exists? Using `open` with mode `a` will create the file if it does not exist and append to it if it exists.

**Note:** `open` will not create missing folders for you!

Additionally, I would recommend to use Python's `with` statement (see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) tutorial), as it will take care the file gets closed even if an exception is raised.

Combining everything said above your program would end up like this:

```
import os

name = "Test" # I had to come up with something
class_number = input("Please enter your class: ")
score = input("Please enter your score: ")

folder = "Class" + class_number
file_name = name + ".txt"
path = os.path.join(folder, file_name)
if os.path.exists(path):
    print("File found")
else:
    print("File not found. Creating file")

with open(path, "a") as txt_file:
    txt_file.write(score + "\n")
```

In general, please check back with your Python reference. As someone told you in a comment, there are a lot of unnecessary parentheses and the style in naming your variables is not really consistent (have a look at Python's "official/recommended" [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)).

There are good online resources showing you the basics of Python. I personally enjoyed learning through [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/) a lot (it's absolutely free).

Comment: Many thanks! Its working fine now (I'm sure you're not surprised). I'm a Python newbie - my school never really taught me the fundamentals of Python, just what we needed to know to code properly. Thanks for the links, will read them.

Comment: @Eric1108 That does not sound like a pleasant learning experience.

Comment: You could say that again :(